# how to create ecommerce order model with multiple products in django rest / node so product price change dont effect

Tags: node.js, django-rest-framework

Assuming an order model with foreign key to multiple products items with quantity....how to main in such way that change of price of product dont affect recalculation in django rest and node js.

What is best way? Any way to main versions or should i make a history model seperate for every product.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```